# extract number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string:

```
name:demo;morestuff.nbvideo:3;morestuff_here:45
```

from which I need to extract the nbvideo number. I managed it with 2 regexes, but I'm sure it can be done in just one regex.

Here's what I have now:

```
// get the nbvideo:XX part
videoPart = sink.tag.match(/nbvideo:([0-9]+)/gi);
// get the number from the video part
videoCount = videoPart[0].match(/([0-9]+)/gi)[0];
```

How can I extract the number behind 'nbvideo:' with one single regex?

Comment: Just use the capturing group in the first regex.

Comment: Remove `g` from the modifiers and access it via index 1. `sink.tag.match(/nbvideo:([0-9]+)/i)[1]` (add error checking of course)

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew.... works like a charm

Comment: that wont help. If you are using indexes then you can use string split by `.nbvideo:` and use index to get first character. But will the number be only a single digit is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `g` from the modifiers and access the first capture group value like this:

```js
var sink_tag = "name:demo;morestuff.nbvideo:3;morestuff_here:45";
var m = sink_tag.match(/nbvideo:([0-9]+)/i);
if (m) {
   videoPart = m[1];
   document.body.innerHTML = videoPart; // demo
}
```

The thing is that [`string#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) does not keep captures if a global modifier is used with a regex, and it seems you just have one `nbvideo:<NUMBER>` in the input. So, removing `/g` seems to be enough. Else, use [`RegExp#exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a loop.